# Creating a Communication site on SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I am unable to see this link [Create Communication site](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-communication-site-in-SharePoint-Online-7fb44b20-a72f-4d2c-9173-fc8f59ba50eb) on my SharePoint page while other users could able to. I am a Tenant admin though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are two possible reasons:

1. When you create a communication site, an Office 365 group is not
   created. However, in order to create a communication site, you must
   have permission to create Office 365 Groups in Outlook.
2. Some functionality is introduced gradually to organizations that
   have opted in to the First Release program. This means that you may
   not yet see this feature or it may look different than what is
   described in the help articles.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-communication-site-in-SharePoint-Online-7fb44b20-a72f-4d2c-9173-fc8f59ba50eb

Answer (score 1):

In order to create a `communication site`, you must have permission to create Office 365 Groups in Outlook otherwise you will not be able to create a `Communication Site`

Comment: How to disable users to create office 365 groups. Where that option is available?